# Using template parameters as function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I can infer template parameters with function parameters

```
template <typename T>
void f(T a)
{ /* */ }

f(4); // T inferred to be `int`
```

However I can't use function parameters to infer template parameters, which aren't types:

```
template <int I>
void g(int I)  // error: declaration of 'I' shadows template parameter
{ /* */ }
```

---

Let's say I want to write a function `divive_dy_2(int number)` and I want to make sure `number` is not zero.

[I've seen a very simple way to do this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), which would require me to pass the argument to a template parameter, which then would use SFINAE to disable it, if it was 0.

But it feels counter-intuitive to expose something like this in an API. Is there some workaround?

<s>(And yes, I could use exceptions and what not, what would probably even be a better idea, but I'm learning SFINAE at the moment and want to know where it's limits are)</s>

Comment: Template parameter must be known at compile time. The value of the argument (as opposed to its type) is not known until run time. Similarly, SFINAE works at compile time. Ain't no way you can use it to somehow act on a value that only becomes known at run time. Basically, if I have `int x; cin >> x; g(x);`, you expect this code to magically fail to compile now if the user types in `0` in the future, but compile successfully if she will have typed `1`.

Comment: `However I can't use function parameters to infer template parameters, which aren't types:`. Well, you can; [for example](http://ideone.com/KuoWnb)

Comment: You could take a `std::integral_constant` as an argument and use user-defined literals to make the call nicer. You may as well use template arguments at that point though.

Comment: In your first example, `T` is inferred from the type of the function's parameter, not from its value. You can't use the value of a function's parameter to infer anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your argument is known at compile time, you do not even need sfinae for your check - a simple `assert` will provide much better diagnostics.

However, if the argument is not known (which is more likely scenario) than you can not make it template argument, and you have to use exceptions or return error code to indicate that provided argument is outside of supported domain.

Answer (score -1):

Think of template as smth the same as #define

If you want to use 4 as template argument, it's roughly

```
template <int I>
void g()
{ ... here use I as _value_, not type}
```

You can quickly look in Alexandrescu's C++ book for a longer discussion, how to use values in template arguments.

Comment: Why are you confusing people? Templates are **not** something as define.

Comment: This helps to think of them as compile-time, _as_ #define .